# How to create a table in DBT populated with variables and static data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a set of template variables and some static data that is associated, and I would like to create a table using DBT that is populated with those.

I understand *dbt seed* would work for creating tables with static data, but dbt does not substitute Jinja variables in the seed files for dynamic configuration.

From what I understand, using a *dbt model* to create views/tables relies on SELECT. This could make sense given existing alternate source tables or preexisting seed tables, however I want to create and populate a table with variables that are accessible to dbt in a pipeline, or in a similar fashion. I don't think SELECT has the kind of functionality I need here.

How do I create a table using dbt and populate it with variable values and static data?

(This should be really simple, I'm assuming I am missing something obvious.)
For reference: https://docs.getdbt.com/

Comment: Ended up using Ansible to clone the repository with the dbt project files and copy template files with "variables values and static data" into the project prior to subsequent executions.